# Enviar texto para uma textbox, através de outro formulário WInform C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e nesse sistema preciso passar o nome do cliente para uma text box que se encontra em outro form, ou seja precisava que o `TxtCliente` fosse público, para que então eu pudesse ir no form principal e colocasse: `TxtCliente.Text = Valor X;` mas o que acontece é que parece que não consigo deixar esse text box público, pois já fiz de tudo e ele não aparece em outros forms que não seja o seu, segue tudo em anexo

[image: imagem das propriedades do textbox]

no entanto, não consigo chamar ele por nenhum outro, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Não infelizmente não responde,

Comment: Por que não responde?

Comment: Não consegui entender a lógica do sistema do cara, só preciso saber como chamar o TxtCliente por outra tela.

Comment: Quando você vai no form secundário e coloca o valor No Txtcliente e retorna para o form principal. Este form principal já está aberto ou você está chamando ele novamente?

Comment: Já esta aberto...